# How to replace Fedora with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, bios

I installed Fedora a few months ago on my Sony Vaio model PCG-71511L laptop.

I created a DVD and even a USB flash drive with Ubuntu. When I restart my laptop, it restarts and runs Fedora.

Pressing **Delete**, **F2** or **F10** when the system is booting has no effect. The boot process continues, arrives at the Grub Boot Menu from Fedora and then boots to Fedora.

---

It seems that I am somehow locked out of my BIOS setup, and therefore I can't change the boot order so that I can boot from a live DVD or live USB flash drive.

How do I get my laptop to boot from either a DVD or a flash drive so that I can install Ubuntu and completely wipe out Fedora?

Comment: This question is more suited for [su]. Either way, try checking your BIOS settings.

Comment: BIOS settings? With this Fedora I have no idea how or where to access the BIOS.

Comment: It is not about Fedora! When you start your PC it gives you the option to open the BIOS settings (by pressing certain keys dependent on the manufacturer). Read [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/283-how-to-access-your-bios-setup).

Comment: Press a key (usually **Delete** but sometimes **F2** or **F10**) while the computer is booting as soon as the splash screen appears to enter the BIOS setup. In the BIOS setup boot sequence, either CD or USB-HDD or both should appear in the boot sequence list before your hard drive in order to enable the laptop to boot from your installation media.

Comment: In Fedora. I did as instructed. It takes me to the GRUB Boot Menu. The options are Fedora and Advance options for Fedora. I can press 'e' to edit commands before boot or 'c' for a command line...What should I do? I dont see any of what karel mentioned that is similar to windows OS

Comment: Berfore you get to GRUB you are in BIOS mode. Usually it says how to enter BIOS (Usually F2 or Delete) and you may try holding in Esc if your BIOS has a way to select boot device once. On one of my computers I can only do this when the computer has been completely shut down.

Comment: In Google search for _images BIOS splash screen_ to see some examples of what a BIOS splash screen looks like. When the computer is booting, you see the BIOS splash screen before you get to the Grub boot menu.

Comment: Please give us the model number and make (HP, Compaq, Dell, etc) of your laptop and we can explain clearly how to get the laptop to boot off of a flash drive or DVD.

Comment: Sony Vaio model PCG-71511L that used to run Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

1) Turn on the computer.
2) Press the F2 key when the VAIO logo appears.
The BIOS setup screen appears.

If the screen does not appear, restart the computer and press the F2 key several times
when the VAIO logo appears

source:https://docs.sony.com/release/VPCEE_VPCEF_series.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the boot screen and look for what key needs to be pressed for the boot menu. For HP this is F9, for Dell and many others it is F12.

If there is no option, enter the BIOS screen (press F2 at boot), find the boot options, and move your CD/DVD drive to the first slot for booting to an Ubuntu DVD, or move the USB mass storage drive to the first slot. Reboot with USB drive or DVD inserted and get ready for Ubuntu magic!